# Without using WPF, how to make forms looks like Windows 7 style or at least looks like more in modern style

Tags: c#, winforms, winforms-interop

Any suggestions? Any 3rd party tools? if 3rd party tool, prefering open source/free one?

Answer (score 1):

Can you give specific examples of which controls present what kind of problems? In general, Windows 7 should skin most WinForms controls. If you are interested in using Windows 7 features in a WinForms app, try the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack). But more details would help ...

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Telerik Winforms Controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx). Some sample [here](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/sample-applications.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[Infragistics .Net Advantage for WinForms](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms.aspx) contains many WinForms controls with Office 2010-like appearance and behaviors.